# How to mute an html object tag content

Tags: html, object, volume

I have an html `<object>` in my site. I would like to mute content.

I have tried numerous variations of code

```
<object data="test.mp3">
<embed volume="0"/>
</object>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard API for interacting for media loaded into objects, so you can't.

If you were to use the `<audio>` element then you could set:

```
document.querySelector("audio").volume = 0;
```

… with JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks. I need to use object tag, because clients might load images, flash files, movie files. I just need it to be mute

Comment: Then the first line of the answer applies.